# Why can't I use hardcore mode in Minecraft Windows 10?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I can't seem to find how to use hardcore mode in Minecraft Windows 10 Edition. Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 4):

Hardcore mode is only available in the Java Edition. No other versions of Minecraft currently support hardcore mode.